# Is it possible to allow anonymous users to access part of an Azure website which uses Active Directory

Tags: anonymity, active-directory, azure

I have a website hosted in Azure that uses Active Directory to prevent anyone from accessing it except for a few test users. Now I would like to expose a single page so that anyone can access it.
I've tried using an AllowAnonymous attribute on my Controller method, and I've tried setting

> <allow users="*" />

in the web.config, but neither appears to have any effect. Is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: How are you hosting the site? Via a VM? web worker? or some other service?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean... When I log into the Azure portal, it is listed under the "Web apps" tab. I don't see anything indicating whether its running as a VM or web worker.  How can I tell?

Comment: You would know and you've already answered so that's OK :) You might want to check out some of the other services on offer though at some point. You are using a web app which offers limited configuration in exchange for being cheap.

Comment: I think that you need to create a "folder" in your web hierarchy because you can give that a different configuration to the main site configuration. Sorry, I'm not an expert so that's about all I know.